# Batch file renaming and moving and variables and things

Tags: batch-file

So I have this Bat file I was able to get working today. I need the files to be renamed before they are moved but for some reason it cannot find the file when I add Ren "%%G" before the Copy.

Here is my code, I hope someone will be able to help me.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "E:\Paqtrack\Download\PDF\"
FOR %%G IN (*.pdf) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %%a IN ("%%G") do (
        set "outFolder=\\appauto1\LazarusAttachments\%%a"
        for /D %%i in (*.*) do (
           for /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %%b IN ("%%i") do (
               if "%%a"=="%%b" set "outFolder=%%i"
             )
         )
         if not exist "!outfolder!" md "!outfolder!"
         copy "%%G" "!outfolder!"
      )
   )
popd
```

Comment: I was in the process of deleting the other one, I apologize.

Comment: If you rename `%%G` to something else *before* copying `%%G`, it is obvious that `copy` cannot find the source, unless you put the *new* name as the copy source... anyway, the question is: what is the new name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ren`, try just setting a name variable, and then adding it to the end of the outfolder.
For example:

```
set "name=foo.bar"
copy "%%G" "!outfolder!/%name%"
```